# How do I get parameters from URL using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I  have URL adresses like this:

> http:://www.mywebsite.com/myapp?brand=nameOfBrand&user=0123456&type=comm

I have to use that info to show the logo of 'nameOfBrand'.
So if I get `brand=google`, the logo of Google will appear, if I get `brand=Amazon`, the logo of Amazon appears, and so on...

Do you know how I can get this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var url_string = "http://www.mywebsite.com/myapp?brand=nameOfBrand&user=0123456&type=comm"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var brand = url.searchParams.get("brand");
console.log(brand);
```

You can use `URL` to convert it and using `searchParams.get` method to grab the particular value that you want.

For more [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)